# Getting returned ruby variables from ruby script by ajax calls to ruby script

Tags: jquery, ruby

I have an issue on how to return ruby variables to javacript jquery ajax calls.
The code looks something like this:

i using jquery ajax calls request to get back ruby data variables,how do i achieve that?
I want my ruby script returntest variable data to be returned to the jquery function.
By the way i am using purely Ruby,no Rails.

index.html

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $.get("test.rb", function(data, status){
            alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
        });
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<button>Send an HTTP GET request to a page and get the result back</button>

</body>
</html>
```

test.rb

```
`returntest="returned data"`
```

Comment: Do you have another server running, if you're not using Rails?

Answer (score 0):

You can put the ruby result in a hidden html tag, and get the result in your javascript code.

However, if you use rack-based framework, I recommend you to use the gem [Gon](https://github.com/gazay/gon)

Comment: what i mean is something like asp.net                         
Request.Form("name")                                                                                             to retreive the variable name from the ajax call passing parameters

Comment: I am not familiar with asp.net very much, but I guess it is kind of web framework. Ruby is a kind of programming language, not a framework. If you implement your own web framework (HTTP level) in Ruby something like Rails or Sinatra, thats ok. If there is no web framework, it is not fair for Ruby.